# counter not incrementing by desired amount

Tags: python, counter

I am doing a code in python for amount of calories needed by a user and how much of one specific food they will need to eat per day to ensure their calorie needs are met.For this, I have created a dictionary which stores different keys which are foods, and values which are how much calories the food is. I have included a random generator, so it randomly picks one of the foods from the dictionary (by converting to a list) and this part works all fine. after picking a food, the while loop starts. Say the calories of the randomly generated food was 300 and the user required 1200 calories. The while loop would make sure that until the randomly generated food is equal to the calories needed by the user, the calories of the randomly generated food keeps getting added on to a separate variable until that variable is equal to the amount of calories needed by the user. Whilst this is happening, there will be another counter being incremented each time there is another portion of the food required.
Lets go back to the example. The food, for example a banana gives 300 calories but the user needs 1200. Because 300 is smaller than 1200, there is a variable lets call it CURRENT_CALORIES which is adding up all the 300s to compare it later to the 1200, and it stores this 300 in it. Now that it has stored this 300, a variable called amount is keeping track of how many bananas are needed to fulfil the users calorie demands, so when another 300 calories (1 banana) is needed, it increments a counter by one.

My problem is that the correct number of calories needed is displayed however the amount of food needed to give those calories always displays just one. For example, it turned out that on one of my test runs someone needed 1600 calories, whilst the cheerio bowl is 110 calories. Obviously, I would need roughly 16 bowls, however it said I need 0 bowls.

```
def calories():
    print()
    print("C A L O R I E   C A L C U L A T O R")
    print()
    global calorie
    calorie = 0
    
    def male():
        BMR = 88.362+(13.397*weight)+(4.799*height)-(5.677*age)
        calorie = BMR*activity
        print("Your calorie requirements are ", calorie, "kcal")
        print("the total calories you need per day is ", calorie)

    
    def female():
        BMR = 447.593+(9.247*weight)+(3.098*height)-(4.330*age)
        calorie =BMR*activity
        calorie = round(calorie,-2)
        print("the total calories you need per day is ", calorie)

        
    gender= input("Enter your gender, male or female: ")
    weight = int(input("Enter your weight, in kg: "))
    height = int(input("Enter your height, in cm: "))
    age= int(input("Enter your age: "))
    print()
    activitylevel = int(input("""Enter the numbers corresponding to each level
Is your activity level:
1 - Little or no excercise
2 - Light excercise or sports 1-3 days a week
3 - Moderately active or sports 3 - 5 days a week
4 - Very active 6 - 7 days a week
5 - Super active very hard excercise, physical job

-> """))
    activity = [1.2, 1.375, 1.55, 1.725, 1.9]
    activity = activity[activitylevel-1]
    if gender == 'female':
        female()
    elif gender == 'male':
        male()
    print()
    
    calorie = round(calorie,-1)
    food = {"breads":30, "apples":90, "bananas":110,
            "bowl of cheerios":110, " lamb ribs":170,
            "hazelnuts":80}
    random_key = random.choice(list(food.keys()))
    random_value = food[random_key]
    total = 0
    amount = 0
    while total<calorie:
        total += random_value
        amount+= 1
    print()
    print("Thats about the same as ", amount, random_key)
    
calories()
```

This is the code. I didn't know what to do at all because I cannot find anything. I am totally lost. I know I have to try myself but I literally have no clue, everything seems correct to me.
The issue probably lies somewhere in the while loop and it is not incrementing correctly. I did try doing amount = amount+1 even though its the same thing just to make sure, but that has no effect ether. Please can someone help. I would prefer that you just change the area of code that is incorrect or is the problem, rather than changing the whole code to something that you think is a simpler code. I know mine might be more lengthy but I really want it to stay this way.
Thanks a lot for any help.

** I just used the print - statement debugging.
Everything is working fine right until the while loop. The while loop doesnt even seem to work. within the while statement, I said to print the total and amount each time, but nothing was printed.

Comment: I don't immediately see the issue, but consider "print-statement debugging", where you print out the values at various points to confirm that they're what you expect them to be.

Comment: `calorie` remains at 0. You’re trying to set the value in the `male` and `female` functions, but you’re only setting local variables there, not the `calorie` variable you think you’re setting.

Comment: deceze is correct. Look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/) for more details.

Comment: deceze thanks for your help. does this mean that I have set two variables with the same name? and within the male and female functions I cannot use any variable outside the function in it and out of the function I cant use anything in it?

Comment: Scoping rules in a nutshell: when you assign to a variable in a function, by default, a local variable only visible inside that function is created. I say “by default”, because you can influence this behaviour by using the `global` or `nonlocal` keywords *inside the function in question.* You’re trying to do that, but you’re doing it wrong, because you’re doing it in the wrong function. But because all this is messy, you should prefer to explicitly `return` values from functions instead of implicitly modifying other scopes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it is now working because I put global calorie under each def(male) and def(female). sorry if it seems like im being lazy and not trying t do things myself, but how would the return value work? I was returning it before [return calories] under each male/female, but it still didn't work.

Comment: You need to `return` the value, and then assign it to something in the caller: `calorie = male()`. You may see why this makes it more obvious and explicit what is happening? Then you also don’t need any `global`s.

Comment: Voted to close as needing real [mre]... but since two mods did not voiced such concerns retracted my vote... Still, for future posts, especially outside of python tag, please consider providing a really minimal sample - there is no need of bunch of print statement, extremly long explanation, it is also very unlikely you needed real BMI calculation and two functions (`male`/`female`) as one should have been enough,... just keep code to one that show the error with all necessary data to show the problem inline in the code as values.

Comment: what? I dont know what the issue was but i thought it was necessary to send the whole code esp as the issue was near the starting whereas I thought it was the ending. what do you mean by it is unlikely you needed real Bmi calculations? I will keep in mind to not explain to lengthily

Answer (score 1):

Oddly written code. Anyway, your calculated `calorie` value in the `male` and `female` functions is not returned from those functions, so the `calorie` you're comparing with is still set to 0, and `while total<calorie:` is never `True`.

Comment: w hy is it odd?

can you please explain why you must return those functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's nice that you've understood the concept. You will start rocking over a period  of time.

print() is just a statement with we which we can just ensure the output. When you mention print(calorie), this will not be taken as a variable calorie. If this needs to be taken as a variable, use return.

i.e provide a function which returns the calorie as follows.(Remove the functions male() and female())

```
def calorie():
    if gender=='male': BMR = 88.362+(13.397*weight)+(4.799*height)-(5.677*age)
    else: BMR = 447.593+(9.247*weight)+(3.098*height)-(4.330*age)
    return BMR*activity
```

This function needs to be called and used as a variable in the later step. for instance where you rounded of calorie as follows:

```
calorie = round(calorie(),-1)
```

If you are not comfortable, you can declare calorie as a separate variable like this as well:

```
calorie = calorie()
calorie = round(calorie, -1)
```

Comment: that's much more understandable. thanks for the help!